# How to get SSH client IP Address using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, ssh

In SSH server,
I want to get the connected client IP address. 
I use 
`$ who` or `$ w`
can get logged information(include client's IP address)

I just want client's IP address (one thing), use in shell script

Answer (score 7):

It is available as part of the environment variable `SSH_CLIENT`:

```
$ echo "$SSH_CLIENT"
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.0.101 39323 22
$ echo "$SSH_CLIENT" | cut -d' ' -f 1
192.168.0.101
```

Comment: In bash you can use `echo "${SSH_CLIENT%% *}"`

Comment: i use CentOS 7, $SSH_CLIENT variable is empty... ${SSH_CLIENT%% *} and $SSH_CONNECTION too

Comment: I use have this set when using CENTOS 7 (both as server connected from a Linux Mint system, as well as from CentOS 7 system). If you know (by other means) your client IP try: `env | grep YOURIPADDR`.

Answer (score 2):

For all users try

```
w --no-header | awk '{print $1" "$3}'
```

In short

```
w -h | awk '{print $1" "$3}'
```

There you can grep for the username. Keep in mind that a user can login several times and from different locations / IPS. 
You also want to check if you can force the w-command to output IPs instead of hostnames (depends on version -n or -i)

Probably you also have to filter out local logins (console)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `netstat` and `awk`. Assuming that you are using port 22 for the `ssh` protocol:

```
netstat -putan | awk '/:22 / && /ESTABLISHED/ {split($5,result,":"); print result[1]}'
```